# Clear duplicate entry from table based on 3 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to clear my database, i need to erase all duplicate entry based on 3 columns.

I've tryed this:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE prod_assoc_variacao ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (fk_produto, fk_grupo, fk_classificador )
```

But i'm getting errors msg telling i have few rows with duplicate entry, so it doesn't work to delete the duplicate entry.

So i tryed this too:

```
DELETE
FROM prod_assoc_variacao
WHERE prod_assoc_variacao.id IN  (  
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM prod_assoc_variacao
    GROUP BY fk_produto, fk_grupo, fk_classificador
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

But i'm getting [Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'prod_assoc_variacao' for update in FROM clause.

Now i don't know what do, my sql is not very good and have no idea.

I appreciate very mutch any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think using an **ALIAS** will solve the problem. I had a similar error while using **Update** Query, though i am sure. But try using **ALIAS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the table on itself in the delete:

```
delete prod_assoc_variaca from prod_assoc_variaca
  inner join prod_assoc_variaca p2 on prod_assoc_variaca.fk_produto = p2.fk_produto 
    and prod_assoc_variaca.fk_grupo = p2.fk_grupo 
    and prod_assoc_variaca.fk_classificador = p2.fk_classificador
    and prod_assoc_variaca.id < p2.id;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba6df/1)

Just reread your post -- if you want to delete the higher ids, use > instead.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. I've tryed this approach but i was unsure that's right.

Comment: @Guerra -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can use is to make a temp table, select the id's into that and then use the temp table in the delete statement

```
create temporary table t( id integer );

insert into t 
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM prod_assoc_variacao
GROUP BY fk_produto, fk_grupo, fk_classificador
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

DELETE
FROM prod_assoc_variacao
WHERE prod_assoc_variacao.id IN (
    select id from t
)
```